# Turn Internet connection on

Tags: android

It is possible to active WiFi or mobile internet at the backend from one application?
I create an application which needs Internet access. The app should check the Internet connection when it starts. If there is no connection, then turn WiFi or mobile Internet connection on.

Is this possible?

I use the ConnectiveManager to check connectivity state.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setWifiEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#setWifiEnabled%28boolean%29)() to change the wifi state.

If there are no wifi networks configured, it should automatically use the data network if any.
Use the ConnectivityManager to check if there are any data networks.

Comment: Can i make this simular with mobile net?

Comment: You can not enable Mobile network data without having system privileges granted. This is by design so application can't abuse billable feature. You should show standard Android's settings screen so user can enable that herself.